# BITBUCKET pul request builder Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

How to configure BITBUCKET pull request builder to make it work?
do i need to check POLL scm in jenkins?

Please provide steps how can i configure it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Setup for the plugin is documented on its GitHub page (which I've now linked to from the wiki):
https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin#readme

You should check the "Bitbucket Pull Request Builder" trigger, rather than the "Poll SCM" trigger.